# Python input Job Code

Tags: python, class, input, function

I'm Code doesn't seem to work, I am trying to get input of a job, category, and salary, and store the input

```
class Jobs:

    def GetJob(self):
        name = raw_input('Enter a Job Title: ')
        category = raw_input('Enter what Category that Job is: ')
        salary = raw_input('Enter the salary of that Job: ')
        print name,category, salary

    def __init__(self,name,category,salary):
        self.name = Jobs.GetJob(name)
        self.category = Jobs.GetJob(category)
        self.salary = Jobs.GetJob(salary)


GetJob = Jobs()

print GetJob
```

Comment: It appears you're using "Python 2.x" - so would recommend using `class Jobs(object):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is totally out of good OOP practices, and the first part eandersson's answer too…

A class has for role to store values, get/set them and return (or apply) transformations to its encapsulated values. What you tried to achieve is totally nonsense: you're calling the `GetJob` method of the Jobs class inside another method. It could work if you would have written:

```
def __init__(self,name…):
    self.name = Jobs.GetJob(self, name)
    …
```

But that would be a wrong way to design your program. You'd better stick your class to hold your values and making it good at that, and make another function that helps populate your class:

```
class Jobs:   
    def __init__(self, name, category, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.salary = salary

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Jobs<%s,%s,%s>" % (self.name, self.category, self.salary)

def GetJob():
    name = raw_input('Enter a Job Title: ')
    category = raw_input('Enter what Category that Job is: ')
    salary = raw_input('Enter the salary of that Job: ')
    return Jobs(name, category, salary)

print GetJob()
```

*I do not agree with eandersson's approach because it deceives the purpose of the constructor, by directly calling the GetJob method. Then GetJob is not useful. And one would want to be able to use the Job class without always having the raw inputs at construction.* EDIT: valid only as a comment on the first part of his answer.

And finally, I think that you really misunderstands a lot about programming. You should better read thoroughly a python course like the ones on http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers, because there's really a lot of concepts you ignored to be able to write something like that.

go have a look at:

- http://hetland.org/writing/instant-hacking.html
- http://www.learnpython.org/
- http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/
- http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: +1 because your answer implements a very simple MVC paradigm.

Comment: lol I simply fixed his code to help him get started, love that you somehow managed to name me twice in the post... and btw remove self from the calling GetJob function.

Comment: What I really want to focus on is the *ENCAPSULATION* concept of object oriented programming. Which, of course is inherent of MVC, but given the code in the question, I can tell you that he's far from knowing MVC.

Comment: ahah, ok you got one point for format(), another for `__repr__` over `__str__` and last one for spotting the forgotten `self` :-) But I do believe what's really important is for Chris to learn programming, and even more OOP! And that said, you're right using `Job` instead of `Jobs` is more OO (as it defines only one Job). Though we can discuss about `GetJob` over `CreateJob`, though I think `PopulateJob` would be more accurate :-p

Comment: Personally I am more worried that he is missing the basics behind how classes work in Python as he isn't using self to call a function within the same class.

Comment: Well, I actually began to lecture him on classes, methods etc… But then I figured out that what he actually needs is a step-by-step course from start. Looking at his code, he does not actually understands what he's writing.

Comment: i am 14 and just learning how to program in python thanks for the help

Comment: you're welcome, and don't hesitate to read introduction books to programming and algorithmics. Also go to your local hackerspace, there may be some programing courses and some people that could mentor you, so you can get the good habits. Good luck, it's a hard but really interesting path you're on! :-)